# Allow CORS header when using tonic-web

Tags: rust, cors, grpc, tonic

I've create a gRPC web server like this:

```rust
use tonic_web::GrpcWebLayer;
use tonic::{
    transport::Server,
};

let grpc_web_handle = tokio::spawn(
   Server::builder()
         .accept_http1(true)
         .layer(GrpcWebLayer::new())
         .add_service(
             tonic_web::enable(
                 AuthServer::new(
                     AuthImpl::default()
                 )
             )
         )
         .serve("127.0.0.1:9001".parse()?)
)
//...
```

However, my firefox complains about CORS:

`OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:9001/auth.Auth/Login`:
`(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)`

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 0
date: Wed, 13 Dec 2023 22:25:53 GMT
```

I also tried to wrap the `AuthServer` into `cors(AuthServer::new(...))`

```rust
fn cors<S>(service: S) -> CorsGrpcWeb<S> where
    S: Service<http::Request<hyper::Body>, Response=http::Response<BoxBody>>,
    S: Clone + Send + 'static,
    S::Future: Send + 'static,
    S::Error: Into<BoxError> + Send
{
    CorsLayer::permissive().layer(tonic_web::enable(service)).into_inner()
}
```

Still not working.

```ini
tonic = {version = "0.10.2", features = []}
tonic-web = {version = "0.10.2",features = []}
tokio = { version = "1.34.0", features = ["full"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable CORS you can use below definition

```yaml
tower-http = { version = "0.3", features = ["cors"] }
```

As they said in [this PR](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/pull/1123/files)

> You can customize the CORS configuration composing the [`GrpcWebLayer`] with the cors layer of your choice.

Also found this example in their [issues](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/issues/1524#issuecomment-1732552709)

```rust
  Server::builder()
       .accept_http1(true)
        .layer(
            CorsLayer::new()
                .allow_origin(AllowOrigin::mirror_request())
                .allow_credentials(true)
                .max_age(DEFAULT_MAX_AGE)
                .expose_headers(
                    DEFAULT_EXPOSED_HEADERS
                        .iter()
                        .cloned()
                        .map(HeaderName::from_static)
                        .collect::<Vec<HeaderName>>(),
                )
                .allow_headers(
                    DEFAULT_ALLOW_HEADERS
                        .iter()
                        .cloned()
                        .map(HeaderName::from_static)
                        .collect::<Vec<HeaderName>>(),
                ),
        )
       .layer(GrpcWebLayer::new())
       .add_service(greeter)
       .serve(addr)
       .await?;
```

Also check [this comment](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/pull/1286#issuecomment-1471209046) too.